# Squib: using arrays with "circle" command

Tags: ruby, squib

I'm trying to set several spots for tokens on a card, using the `circle` command. I want to try and use arrays for the x-y coordinates, but it's only printing the first element of the arrays. Here's the relevant line of code:

```
circle x: [75, 150, 325, 500, 675, 750], y: [900, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 900],
radius: 62.5, stroke_width: 2
```

Comment: It appears that `Squib`'s `circle` method requires the values of `x` and `y` (coordinates for the centre) to be integers. Why do you want them to be arrays? Are you trying to draw six circles with the same radius and `stroke_width` (centred on `[75,900]`, `[150,1050]`, and so on)? If so, I think you need something like this: `a = [75, 150, 325, 500, 675, 750]; b = [900, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 900]; a.zip(b).each { |x,y| circle x: x, y: y, radius: 62.5, stroke_width: 2 }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving an array to Squib maps them out to different cards because [Squib Thinks in Arrays](http://squib.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13/arrays.html).

So your code puts circles on the other cards.

To do multiple circles on the same card, do something like this:

```
require 'squib'

Squib::Deck.new(cards: 6) do
  background color: :white
  xs = [75, 150, 325, 500, 675, 750]
  ys = [900, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 900]
  (0..5).each do |i|
    circle x: xs[i], y: ys[i], radius: 62.5, stroke_width: 2
  end
  save_png
end
```

Or you can use the zip answer in the comment to your question.

(Full disclosure: I am the Squib dev.)